# Unable to make a migration. Getting errors related to foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration

First migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Second migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements("post_id");
            $table->bigInteger("author_id");
            $table->string("title");
            $table->string("short_title");
            $table->string("img")->nullable();
            $table->text("descr");
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign("author_id")->references("id")->on("users");
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

After I run the `php artisan migrate` command I'm getting errors.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 
`laralove`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is 
incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_author_id_foreign` foreign key (`author_id`) references `users` (`id`))

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
       // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
        // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
        catch (Exception $e) {
          throw new QueryException(
               $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        }


  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laralove`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOStatement::execute()
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove> php artisan config:cache
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove> php artisan migrate     
Migrating: 2021_06_13_195343_create_posts_table
```

```
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
    
      SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'posts' already exists (SQL: create table `posts` (`post_id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `author_id` bigint not null, `title` varchar(255) not null, `short_title` varchar(255) not null, `img` varchar(255) null, `descr` text not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate 'utf8_general_ci' engine = InnoDB)
    
      at C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
            // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
            // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
             // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
                    $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
               );                            ings($bindings), $e
            }


  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485    work\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectio
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'posts' already er view already exists: 1050 Table 'posxists")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectiowork\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485    
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

**UPD 1**

@miken32 suggested to execute command `php artisan migrate:rollback`
 For some reason I'm getting the following errors:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]   , ..      .
 (SQL: select max(`batch`) as aggregate from `migrations`)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new QueryException(
              $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
           );
       }
  

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]   , ..      .
")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=laralove", "root", "", [])
```

**UPD 2**

I've applied the changes I were suggested by @Amir Daneshkar

And previous errors are gone, but new one's have emerged. I've no clue what can be wrong here.
The new errors:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]   , ..      .
 (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laralove and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a   
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.     
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕

    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]   , ..      .
")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=laralove", "root", "", [])
```

**UPD 2.1.**
I had configured .env and database.php files

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laralove
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laralove'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => "InnoDB",
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
//...
]
```

Comment: drop the table on the db `Base table or view already exists`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the second error is just because they didn't do `migrate:rollback` after the first error.

Comment: Why are your migrations all different? Why `id()` on one table and `bigIncrements()` on another? Why `id` column on `users` and `post_id` on `posts`? Are you just copying and pasting stuff randomly?

Comment: @miken32 I've tried to do php artisan migrate:rollback, but got other errors. I'll put them as an update in my question

Comment: @miken32 I've attached a second updated

Comment: have you tried deleting the database and creating a new one ?

Comment: @AmirDaneshkar have just recreated the database and now it all works!

Comment: Thank you everybody for helping me with my issue. It's been fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the posts migration **post_id** and **author_id** to this :

```
$table->id('post_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
...
```

As I remember Laravel id fields need to be **unsignedBigInts** and the correct   format for defining an id fields is also like this :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->unique()->autoIncerement() ;
```

which has a macro `$table->id('column_name');`

**Update**
after doing so run `php artisan migrate:fresh` , if it throws error, try deleting the database and creating it again

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've changed it the way you wrote. And the initial errors are gone. But I'm getting other errors now. I'll attach them as an update.